# Expo - Remote Config: Indexed DB is not supported by current browser

Tags: javascript, firebase, expo, indexeddb, firebase-remote-config

I have an expo app and tried to add Firebase support to use their remote-config service. I am testing it in this code

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { getRemoteConfig } from "firebase/remote-config";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    authDomain: "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb",
    projectId: "ccccccccccc",
    storageBucket: "ddddddddddddddddddddddddddd",
    messagingSenderId: "eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee",
    appId: "fffffffffffffffffffff",
    measurementId: "gggggggggggggggggg"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
export const config = getRemoteConfig(app);
config.settings.minimumFetchIntervalMillis = 3600000;
config.defaultConfig = {
    "test": "Welcome222222"
};
config.getValue("test");
```

But when i try to run it in Expo Go on Android emulator, i get

**FirebaseError: Remote Config: Indexed DB is not supported by current browser (remoteconfig/indexed-db-unavailable)**

Is there a way to not use any Indexed DB? I thought that the library would just let me use the remote config REST api confortably and i could just send requests, i have no need for any DB in this case.

Comment: Got the same error when running built .apk directly

Comment: were u able to resolve this, m stuck too

Comment: I was not able to resolve this. Have used different library from different provider instead.